# Gremlin console to azure-cosmosdb 404

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have just created an account in Azure portal and followed instructions to create my first graph db form here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-gremlin-console

I have downloaded Gremlin Console `v3.3.0` from Apache Thinkerpop website, and updated the `remote-secure.yaml` in according to the documentation. However, every time I tried to connect, by calling the following command

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-secure.yaml
```

the Gremlin console returns

`WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster  - SSL configured without a trustCertChainFile and thus trusts all certificates without verification (not suitable for production)
ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler  - Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 404 Not Found
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:158)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:210)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:73)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:312)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1296)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1087)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1122)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:491)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:430)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
==>Configured mygraph.graphs.azure.com/13.76.242.167:443`

Then I thought i might be my configuration and created a `Persons` sample project from the portal quick start. The config looks like that:

```
hosts: [myGraph.graphs.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/graphdb/colls/Persons
password: myPrimaryKey
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

It basically looks the same to my original configuration, apart from `username` value contains different `db` and `collection` names. However, when I connect to remote in console it returns the same error.

I thought it could be a firewall on the portal, but it's currently turned off.

Just in case if it matters, my OS is macOS.

Comment: We have the same problem. Using Linux.

Comment: I am facing the exact issue, my OS is Centos/Linux. If anyone has experience of solving above problem, please do help.

Comment: I don't think this is an OS issue. However, I have experimented over the last few days. I have tried different DB names and regions. It was all the same until I have added '-' to the DB name. And it worked twice in the raw. I'm still not confident if it's a coincident or not. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your endpoint to `xxxx.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com` and have a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and [@Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717341/lukas-knuth)'s answer solved it for me.

Here's the content of my configuration file:

```
# Connect securely to remote Cosmos DB via Gremlin API
# Use .gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com to avoid infinite stack trace
hosts:
  - <account-name>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com
port: 443
# Find your database name and collection ID in the Azure portal
username: /dbs/<db>/colls/<coll>
# Pick read-write or read-only key
password: <key from Cosmos DB account>
connectionPool:
  enableSsl: true
  # Add cert file to avoid this error:
  # WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster  - SSL configured without a trustCertChainFile and thus trusts all certificates without verification (not suitable for production)
  trustCertChainFile: /etc/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
serializer:
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0
  config:
    serializeResultToString: true
```

---

Also, I'm using this Docker image to start the Gremlin console: [cruftlab/gremlin-console](https://hub.docker.com/r/cruftlab/gremlin-console/) (which contains the certificate used in `connectionPool.trustCertChainFile`).

I created two folders: `gremlin-data/{conf,data}`, and stored the configuration (the one I pasted above) in `gremlin-data/conf/cosmosdb.yaml`. Then I fired up the Gremlin console with this command:

```
docker run --rm -it \
  -v $(pwd)/gremlin-data/conf:/opt/gremlin/conf/extra \
  -v $(pwd)/gremlin-data/data:/opt/gremlin/data \
  cruftlab/gremlin-console
```

Now, the configuration file you loaded should be accessible within the image (under `conf/extra`). So now you should be able to connect to Cosmos DB by running this command (within the Gremlin console):

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/extra/cosmosdb.yaml
==>Configured <account-name>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com/<ip address>:443
gremlin>
```

And there you go!

---

Also, you *should* be able to import/export between Cosmos DB and the `data` volume, but I've only tested this locally so far. :)

**Credits:**

- [SSL warn while connecting Azure COSMOSDB(Gremlin API) from Gremlin console/driver](https://ourwayoflyf.com/ssl-warn-while-connecting-azure-cosmosdb-gremlin-api-with-gremlin-console/)
- [Azure Cosmos DB: Create, query, and traverse a graph in the Gremlin console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-gremlin-console#ConnectAppService)